# Physical shocks, even small ones from slight movement, cause laptop to shut down

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

I Have a 4 years old Lenovo G570 Corei5-2430M.

It's just, when  i give it some shock (even just slides it a little on the table), 
The screen will flash to random color for about 3 sec, and then the laptop die.

I just want to know what is causing this problem.
Having a laptop that can not be moved is really stressed me out. so please help me.

Comment: Hopefully you just have a loose connection somewhere. find someone to take it apart and put it back together again. Based on what you describe, it could be almost anything. Unfortunately, it is possible that the affected component is broken internally. In that case it would need to be replaced. If you do choose to take it apart yourself, be extra careful to mark what screws go where (length is important).

Comment: @frank Hmm.. Ok, i'll try that later... But, 
do you know what could be causing it. something when given shocks can be damaged. I need that for my starting point.

Comment: Few things might be handy. What's the OS? (there might be something useful in the logs). If the laptop on mains or battery power?if it runs windows, is there something like 'active protection' on the hard drives?

Comment: My first guess is HDD, since the component would likely need to have some mass to react to the jostling, and the fact that it magically fixes itself, but that is just a guess. There is little point to having a "starting point" in that taking the laptop apart to ensure that the video card does not wiggle in its connector to the motherboard and has a solid connection to the monitor is no differant from taking it apart to ensure that the wnic is solidly connected. Certianly check the items you can get to first, but what you describe could indicate any device was unexpectedly disconnected.

Comment: Thanks @frank. I only use your first suggestions and it worked. If you want to post that as an answer, i'll mark it.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would check HDD and more probably RAM first. If you previously opened this laptop (for basic things like changing HDD and RAM) that would be easy. Keep in mind every unwanted and unplanned reset will cause much more trouble to your hardware. After checking HDD and RAM, if problem still exists, that will sound more like deeper problem (like power related problems) bring it to a technical service.

Hope to be solved soon.